# mp4 streaming with jwplayer and download speed limit

Tags: php, performance, download, streaming, mp4

hi everyone i have a problem with my streaming. at the moment i have made jwplayer to open a php file (ex. movie2.php) and this php file gives to the jwplayer the movie file pice by pice by sleeping 1 second to limit the speed (this php file also checks referer and session and doesnt show the video path but that but these are not important for the problem)  . until here everything is perfect but the problem is : I **can not seek** the video to a not loaded part and it is obvious the reason why . **so can anyone tell me how should i do this ?** i need to change this php file somehow to make it support the streaming or can anyone give me a script that supports the streaming and limit the download speed at the same time ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "**start=**" value passed to your php code. I've used the JW Player before, and it definitely supports seek. [Apparently](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/7362/pseudo-streaming-and-seeking#comment-34866), a seek is more like a restart, and passes that 'start' to your php file. From there, your file just starts the playing at that point.

There's a couple other comments on that thread about handling the client side of the object to avoid a couple pitfalls. It may be a bit dated, but should be relevant.

Comment: wow man you are genious ! but the problem is when i use fseek to serve the file from that point and jwplayer gives error :video not found because of the meta data (i think) i need to put the meta data at anytime the video is started at the begining of the file that i should create but i dont know how many bytes at the begining of the mp4 are these metadata